# Android Studio:No variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists. at: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

```
No variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists. at:
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidModule.prepare(GradleModules.kt:266)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncProjectActionWorker.populateAndroidModels(SyncProjectActionWorker.kt:99)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:92)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderImpl.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:112)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProvider.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:50)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:400)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:138)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:104)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:84)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:57)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:81)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:98)
  org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:177)
  org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:258)
  org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:177)
  org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
  org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:177)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:95)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:73)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
```

I've tried modifying the JDK and gradle versions and found no effect
My Android Gradle Plugin Version : 8.0.2
My Gradle Version : 8.0
My JDK version 11